# Changing Default Teams Sharepoint Site Language

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Someone invited me to a Teams site, my site page however is in Spanish. When I click to view in Sharepoint all the buttons, links, and similar controls (or widgets) are in Spanish. Oddly enough the folders, and file contents are in English.

I checked the default language of my PC, Teams Application, and Sharepoint site and all seem to indicate that it is supposed to default to English, even as a preference. For the life of me I don't know why all the controls remain in Spanish.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different parts of Teams are governed by different settings.  If you are viewing Teams with the Teams desktop app and not the browser, the interface of Teams itself is determined by the app language settings.  However the language of most, not all, of the SharePoint UI elements within Teams depends on a variety of SharePoint settings and setup.  Teams sites are typically created with one base language and 49 alternate languages.  It is possible to delete any or all of the alternate languages if you don't want to support them.  Which language the SharePoint UI will be in will depend on the languages in your SharePoint profile. If that is blank or doesn't match the base or alternate languages, it depends on your browser language settings.    If there is not match there either, it will be in the base language.

Of course if nobody localized the column names, those column headers will be in the base language of the site no matter what the other settings say.

Dates, on the other hand, can depend on the user's *locale* settings, not their *language* settings and, unlike UI language, there is another setting to determine if your locale or the site's is used, and force dates and currency to be displayed in the site's locale, vs. the user's locale.

More details here
https://blog.icefire.ca/blogs/teams-localization/

Comment: Based on this response it definitely sounds like something that the SP admin would have to address vs. the user. The user settings are all set to English across the board on the PC, Portal, Browser..etc but for some reason does not change. There was a theory that perhaps the language packs would have to be dropped to "- force" the site to default to English. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This is SharePoint Online so the admin has no access to language packs.  The most likely cause of this is that the Team and its SharePoint site were created with Spanish as the base language.  That base language cannot be changed, the Team would have to be deleted and re-created.  Another alternative which will solve most but not all of the problem is to fully populate the MUI, adding English translations for all the columns, and to change the site's locale setting for the dates.